# How to log the insert update and delete in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my csv is below

```
Date,ProductID,Price,Quantity
2023-01-01,1001,10,1
2023-01-02,1001,10,1
2023-01-02,1011,10,6
```

My output_data.csv below

```
ProductID,TotalSales
1001,20
1011,60
```

if I am adding csv row and updating also deleting the input csv the output_data.csv has to reflect

new input csv

```
Date,ProductID,Price,Quantity
2023-01-01,1001,10,2
2023-01-02,1001,10,1
2023-01-02,1011,10,6
2023-01-02,1012,10,6
```

My output would be below

```
ProductID,TotalSales,OperationType
1001,30, Updated
1011,60, No Change
1012,60, Insert
```

OperationType you can see 1001 is Updated as value changed from 20 to 30
OperationType you can see 1011 is No Change as no change in value
OperationType you can see 1012 is Insert as 1012 is first time its getting inserted to ouput_Data.csv

My code is below

```
import pandas as pd
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def extract(file_path):
    """Extract data from a CSV file."""
    return pd.read_csv(file_path)

def transform(data):
    """Transform data by calculating total sales."""
    data['TotalSales'] = data['Price'] * data['Quantity']
    return data.groupby('ProductID')['TotalSales'].sum().reset_index()

def load(data, output_file_path):
    """Load data into a new CSV file."""
    data.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)

def insert_data(data, new_data):
    """Insert new data into the existing dataset."""
    updated_data = pd.concat([data, new_data], ignore_index=True)
    return updated_data

def delete_data(data, condition):
    """Delete rows based on a condition."""
    deleted_rows = data[condition]
    updated_data = data.drop(data[condition].index)
    return updated_data, deleted_rows

def update_data(data, condition, update_values):
    """Update data based on a condition."""
    updated_rows = data.loc[condition].copy()
    data.loc[condition, update_values.columns] = update_values.values
    return data, updated_rows

def identify_operation(original_data, updated_data):
    """Identify operation type for each row."""
    merged = pd.merge(original_data, updated_data, on='ProductID', how='outer', suffixes=('_old', '_new'), indicator=True)
    
    operations = []
    for index, row in merged.iterrows():
        if row['_merge'] == 'left_only':
            operations.append('No Change')
        elif row['_merge'] == 'right_only':
            operations.append('Insert')
        else:
            if row['TotalSales_old'] != row['TotalSales_new']:
                operations.append('Updated')
            else:
                operations.append('No Change')
    
    return pd.Series(operations, name='OperationType')  # Return as a Series

def run_pipeline(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    """Run the data pipeline."""
    data = extract(input_file_path)
    transformed_data = transform(data)
    original_data = transformed_data.copy()

    # Identify operation types
    operations = identify_operation(original_data, transformed_data)
    transformed_data = pd.concat([transformed_data, operations], axis=1)  # Concatenate as a new column
    load(transformed_data[['ProductID', 'TotalSales', 'OperationType']], output_file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_pipeline('data.csv', 'output_data.csv')
```

I am getting below output_data.csv

```
ProductID,TotalSales,OperationType
1001,30,No Change
1011,60,No Change
1012,60,No Change
```

> > OperationType was wrong, every time its coming No Change

Comment: Sorry, what are you asking? If you're asking if Pandas can do this for you, I don't think so, but have you done any research? If you're asking how to do it yourself, then what have you tried?

Comment: Insert, delete and update what?  The dataframe or the csv file? I think the only way to keep track of changes like this would be by storing data in a database structure and adding columns to identify date/time of creation, change date/time. and change action.

Comment: @itprorh66 in the output file

Comment: You can do this via logging module from python (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ARI4Cz-awo&ab_channel=CoreySchafer)

Answer (score 1):

You are basically comparing two identical output files. You must take into account the previous output when running `run_pipeline`. I have rewritten your function:

```
def run_pipeline(input_file_path, previous_output_file_path, output_file_path):
    """Run the data pipeline."""
    data = extract(input_file_path)
    transformed_data = transform(data)
    original_data = extract(previous_output_file_path)

    # Identify operation types
    operations = identify_operation(original_data, transformed_data)
    transformed_data = pd.concat([transformed_data, operations], axis=1)  # Concatenate as a new column
    load(transformed_data[['ProductID', 'TotalSales', 'OperationType']], output_file_path)
```

In main you must call it in this way:

```
run_pipeline('new_data.csv', "output_data.csv", 'new_output_data.csv')
```

where `new_data.csv` is:

```
Date,ProductID,Price,Quantity
2023-01-01,1001,10,2
2023-01-02,1001,10,1
2023-01-02,1011,10,6
2023-01-02,1012,10,6
```

`output_data.csv` is:

```
ProductID,TotalSales
1001,20
1011,60
```

given these two inputs, `run_pipeline` produces `new_output_data.csv` that is:

```
ProductID,TotalSales,OperationType
1001,30,Updated
1011,60,No Change
1012,60,Insert
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
import logging

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# ... (other functions remain the same)

def run_pipeline(input_file_path, output_file_path):
    """Run the data pipeline."""
    data = extract(input_file_path)
    transformed_data = transform(data)

    # Load existing output data (if exists)
    try:
        original_data = load('output_data.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logging.info("Output file not found, starting with fresh data.")
        original_data = transformed_data.copy()

    # Identify operation types
    operations = identify_operation(original_data, transformed_data)
    transformed_data = pd.concat([transformed_data, operations], axis=1)

    load(transformed_data[['ProductID', 'TotalSales', 'OperationType']], output_file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_pipeline('data.csv', 'output_data.csv')
```

With these adjustments, the code correctly identifies and tracks changes in the output data, producing the desired output:

```html
ProductID,TotalSales,OperationType
1001,30,Updated
1011,60,No Change
1012,60,Insert
```

Comment: load('output_data.csv'), load function require 2 args